# Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I try to run a test on a fragmentDialog that is anchored to a viewId in its hosting activity

```
  @Test
  public void largeScreenDeviceUsesPopup() {
    final FragmentUtilActivity fragmentActivity = new FragmentUtilActivity();
    fragmentActivity.onCreate(null);

    myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.create(FragmentUtilActivity.anchorId);
    myDialogFragment.showNow(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

    assertThat(....)
  }

  private static class FragmentUtilActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

  public static int anchorId = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
      view.setId(anchorId);

      setContentView(view);
    }
  }
```

however i get this error:

```
Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Do not manually create an activity in tests or anywhere. Use `ActivityRule` or `ActivityScenario` in tests to test activity functionality.

Comment: Where is the code to init the view model? also it think it is bad idea to call `onCreate(null)` , you should never call life cycle methods manually

Comment: @CommonsWare but i need to pass an anchorViewId

Comment: @MaksimNovikov can you please explain? which is the view model?

Comment: Set that up via `Intent` extras. Or, use dependency injection, test-specific resource overrides, or something else.